# How do I convert a phone number to a ContactJid in Whatsapp4j?

Tags: java, types, whatsapp

how do I convert a phone number to a `ContactJid`?.
For example I have a certain phone number:

`int PhoneNumber = 12313112;`

I want to sent a message to that number through [Whatsapp4j](https://github.com/Auties00/WhatsappWeb4j) but in order to do this we have to get the chat.

```
var chat = api.store()
 .findChatByJid(ContactJid);
```

how can I replace the `ContactJid` with a phone number?. I don't really know how to make a `ContactJid`.

Comment: Did you want the Java tag on this question? Because I see 'var', which makes me think this is either kotlin or JavaScript. Either way here is the documentation for ContactJid. https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.auties00/whatsappweb4j/latest/it.auties.whatsappweb4j/it/auties/whatsapp/model/contact/ContactJid.html

Comment: @JonR85 `var` was introduced in Java 11, see: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8193259

Comment: huh, well I'll be...

Comment: @JonR85, my bad, even earlier in Java 10: https://developer.oracle.com/learn/technical-articles/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference (no more offtop comments, sorry :D )

Comment: @JonR85 the problem is that i don't know how to make a ContactJid, so the ContactJid requires a` String user` how do we get the user? and the ContactJid requires a `Server server` how do we get that?